# Problems with for loops in batch file

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to create a for loop in batch with some calculation using modulus from 1-100 then return an average for the entire set of numbers. I want to print this average on the screen and to a file called output This is what i have but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Any suggestions? Thank you kindly.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnabledDelayedExpansion
for /l %%i in (1,1,100) do (
    set /a EXPR = %%i %% 5
    set /a EXPR2 = %EXPR+3
    set /a TOTAL = TOTAL+%EXPR2
) 
set /a AVG = %TOTAL/100
echo Your average is %AVG
echo Your average is %AVG >> output.txt
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain us with a little example how did want calculate this average step by step ?

Comment: See `setlocal /?` and `for /?` for an explanation of why your code doesn't work. Apart from that your variables are all wrong. It's `%Var%` not `%Var`.

Comment: You cannot read variables like `%AVG`, is must read `%AVG%` in the `echo`s; within `set /A`, do not state the `%` signs but use `set /A EXPR2=EXP+3`, for instance; and it is called `EnableDelayedExpansion` (not `Enable`**`d`**), although you do not need delayed expansion here anyway; finally, you could write `set /A TOTAL+=EXPR2` instead of `set /A TOTAL=TOTAL+EXPR2` (it means the same)...

Comment: Thank you everyone, i am new to batch so the syntax is throwing me off a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%i in (1,1,100) do (
    set /a EXPR=%%i %% 5
    set /a EXPR2=EXPR+3
    set /a TOTAL=TOTAL+EXPR2
) 
set /a AVG=TOTAL/100
echo Your average is %AVG%
echo Your average is %AVG%
```

Is this what you want?

One additional `d` in EnableDelayedExpansion (btw. `set /a` works also without delayed expansion). Classical error is to let spaces surrounding variable assignment.In batch scripts result is that the space becomes part of the variable name.Except FOR tokens and command line arguments variables are two side enclosed with `%`

Comment: For `set /A`, spaces around the `=` do not matter (opposed to standard-`set`, where they become part of the variable name and/or value, as you described)...

Comment: Thank you much.  This helped me understand it better. Problem solved.